# is there any operation like socket.recv_into in python 3 asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Socket module has a `socket.recv_into` method, so it can use user-defined `bytebuffer` (like `bytearray`) for zero-copy. But perhaps `BaseEventLoop` has no method like that. Is there a way to use method like `socket.recv_into` in asyncio?

Answer (score 1):

The low-level socket operations defined for `BaseEventLoop` require a `socket.socket` object to be passed in, e.g. `BaseEventLoop.sock_recv(sock, nbytes)`. So, given that you have a `socket.socket`, you could call `sock.recv_into()`. Whether it is a good idea to do that is another question.

Comment: I already use  `loop.sock_recv`. but `loop.sock_recv` returns bytes object.  So I also use `bytearray.extend method`
ex)

`ba = bytearray();
bytes_object = yield from loop.sock_recv(some_sock);
ba.extend(bytes_object)
`

`sock_recv` don't use pre-created fixed-size `bytearray`.

Comment: I want a way like `precreated_buffer = bytearray(b' ' * 100); loop.sock_recv_into(some_socket, precreated_buffer, 100)`

Comment: @SeungHyunHwang: I understand that, however, I was suggesting that you could call _`sock.recv_into()`_ on the socket instead of `loop.sock_recv()`. I have no idea whether that is a safe thing to do within the asyncio framework - I suspect not.

Comment: thank you for your comment @mhawke  :)  I'll experiment it! Because `sock.recv_into` is not coroutine,  It will be likely to fail :(

Comment: @SeungHyunHwang: You could subclass `BaseEventLoop` and provide a coroutine implementation of `recv_into()`.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* implement own asyncio transport which utilizes `.recv_into()` function but yes, for now asyncio has not a way to use `.recv_into()` out-the-box.

Personally I doubt in very big speedup: when you develop with C the zero-copy is extremely important but for high-level languages like Python benefits are much lesser.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Starting with Python 3.7.0, which is in alpha release as I write this, the standard library's asyncio module documents AbstractEventLoop.sock_recv_into().

Edit: expanding answer as requested...

A call to asyncio's `sock_recv_into()` typically looks like:

```
byte_count = await loop.sock_recv_into(sock, buff)
```

The buff is a mutable object that implements Python's buffer protocol, examples of which include a bytearray and a memoryview on a bytearray. The code below demonstrates receiving into a bytearray using a memoryview.

Working demo code for asyncio sockets necessarily includes a bunch of scaffolding to set up both sides of the connections and run the event loop. The point here is the use of asyncio's sock_recv_into() in the sock_read_exactly() co-routine below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Demo the asyncio module's sock_recv_into() facility."""

import sys
assert sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 7), (
        'asyncio sock_recv_into() new in Python 3.7')

import socket
import asyncio

def local_echo_server(port=0):
    """Trivial treaded echo server with sleep delay."""
    import threading
    import time
    import random
    ssock = socket.socket()
    ssock.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
    _, port = ssock.getsockname()
    ssock.listen(5)
    def echo(csock):
        while True:
            data = csock.recv(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            time.sleep(random.random())
            csock.sendall(data)
        csock.shutdown(1)
    def serve():
        while True:
            csock, client_addr = ssock.accept()
            tclient = threading.Thread(target=echo, args=(csock,), daemon=True)
            tclient.start()
    tserve = threading.Thread(target=serve, daemon=True)
    tserve.start()
    return port


N_COROS = 100
nrunning = 0

async def sock_read_exactly(sock, size, loop=None):
    "Read and return size bytes from sock in event-loop loop."
    if loop is None: loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    bytebuff = bytearray(size)
    sofar = 0
    while sofar < size:
        memview = memoryview(bytebuff)[sofar:]
        nread = await loop.sock_recv_into(sock, memview)
        print('socket', sock.getsockname(), 'read %d bytes' % nread)
        if not nread:
            raise RuntimeError('Unexpected socket shutdown.')
        sofar += nread
    return bytebuff

async def echo_client(port):
    "Send random data to echo server and test that we get back the same."
    from os import urandom
    global nrunning
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.setblocking(False)
    await loop.sock_connect(sock, ('127.0.0.1', port))
    for size in [1, 64, 1024, 55555]:
        sending = urandom(size)
        await loop.sock_sendall(sock, sending)
        received = await sock_read_exactly(sock, size)
        assert received == sending
    nrunning -= 1
    if not nrunning:
        loop.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = local_echo_server()
    print('port is', port)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for _ in range(N_COROS):
        loop.create_task(echo_client(port))
        nrunning += 1
    print('Start loop.')
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to use `AbstractEventLoop.sock_recv_into()`?  Perhaps include a code sample.